# software for genome wide associations studies (GWAS)

Tags: regression, software, bioinformatics, gwas

I have just started learning about genome wide associations studies (GWAS) as I will have to run some of them in the near future, and I am pretty confused about which are the best computational tools available for my dataset.

In particular, I have almost 10 millions SNPs that I would like to test against clinical numerical covariates such as blood pressure. Moreover, I have some high dimensional phenotypes that I would like to reduce to 40/50 variables using dimensionality reduction (PCA etc.) and test them in the same multivariate model.

Which software/implementation would you advise for performing this statistical analysis, please?

Answer (score 0):

While I personally make my own models in Python there are out of the box libraries for R like [SNPassoc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SNPassoc/SNPassoc.pdf)

I'm going to assume you're an academic if you're asking this question so here's also the link to the [paper](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article-abstract/23/5/654/239565/SNPassoc-an-R-package-to-perform-whole-genome?redirectedFrom=fulltext).

Comment: @fastDio even if you choose to run the computations yourself, if you are at an academic institution get advice early on from a statistician trained in these analyses, as there are many ways the analyses and interpretations can go wrong. You don't want to be in a situation where, after much work, you have to start over again when a reviewer of your manuscript notes a fatal flaw in your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of samples

- [PLINK](http://zzz.bwh.harvard.edu/plink/) Smaller datasets
- [BOLT-LMM](https://data.broadinstitute.org/alkesgroup/BOLT-LMM/) Larger datasets, for example UK Biobank approx. 500K samples / participants

You can find a more comprehensive list here:
https://omictools.com/association-mapping-category